# Nesting columns under a new header column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a time series DataFrame df1 with prices in a ticker column, from which a new DataFrame df2 is created by concatenating df1 with 3 other columns sharing the same DateTimeIndex, as shown:

[image: df1 and df2]

Now I need to set up the ticker name "Equity(42950 [FB])" to become the new header and to nest the 3 other columns under it, and to have the ticker's prices replaced by the values in the "closePrice" column.

How to achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pd.MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html):

```
d = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(5,4), columns=['Equity', 'closePrice', 'mMb', 'mMv'])

arrays = [['Equity','Equity','Equity'],['closePrice', 'mMb','mMv']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)

df = pd.DataFrame(d.values[:, 1:], columns=index)
df

    Equity
    closePrice  mMb mMv
0   1           2   3
1   5           6   7
2   9           10  11
3   13          14  15
4   17          18  19
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much!